# Will I be admitted as a visitor to Canada with a limited travel history?

Tags: visas, canada, nigerian-citizens

I was recently rejected for visas on the grounds I do not have a travel history. I have only been able to visit one nation. Other things about me:

- I am a Nigerian
- I am a Software Engineer for a Financial institution in My home country / Remote Mobile application Developer
- I have been to Benin Republic (Just one country)
- I recently got married, April this year, No child.
- I have Properties in my name inherited from my father

Is this a good fit to apply for a [TRV](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents/visitors/what-visa.html) for Canada?

Comment: Who rejected you? Also, why do you want to visit Canada and for how long?

Comment: Right now visitors are barred from Canada anyways due to covid. "The emergency orders under the Quarantine Act do not allow people to travel to Canada for optional or discretionary reasons, such as for tourism, recreation or entertainment."

Comment: It's also impossible to predict if you will be granted a visa. It depends on juchbyou haven't told us.

Comment: @DJClayworth, i know i said , "I have a job as a software Engineer in a financial institution" a financial institution means bank. i am a programmer in a Bank, I hope you understand

Comment: @DJClayworth, Or i did not understand what else you meant